# NHibernate Could not resolve property

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am getting exception `NHibernate.QueryException` : *could not resolve property: InsuredId*. I am new to NHibernate and I could not figure it out.

Defining Properties

```
public virtual int InsuredId { get; set; }
public virtual string Gender { get; set; }
public virtual DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
public virtual string SrId { get; set; }
public virtual string SchoolId { get; set; }
public virtual string Ssn { get; set; }
public virtual DateTime GradDate { get; set; }
```

Mapping data to properties

```
public InsuredMap()
{
     ReadOnly();

     Table("Insured");
     Id(x => x.Id, "InsuredId");
     Map(x => x.Gender, "SexCd");
     Map(x => x.DateOfBirth, "BirthDt");
     Map(x => x.SrId, "SIDIdNum");
     Map(x => x.SchoolId, "SchoolIdTxt");
     Map(x => x.Ssn, "SocSecNumTxt");
     Map(x => x.GradDate, "GradMthYrNum");
}
```

Function to fetch all values

```
public Entities.Insured GetByInsuredId(int insuredId)
{
    var query = Session.QueryOver<Entities.Insured>()
        .Where(x => x.InsuredId == insuredId)
        .Cacheable()
        .CacheRegion(Constants.EntityCacheRegion);

    return query.SingleOrDefault();
}
```

Unit Test to test the data

```
[Test]
public void InsuredMapTest()
{
    var insured = repository.GetByInsuredId(714619800);
    Assert.That(insured.Gender, Is.EqualTo("F"));
}
```

Comment: It looks like you haven't mapped `InsuredId`, which is why you're getting the exception

Answer (score 11):

Let me be more precise, and extend the Andrew Whitaker comment.

In the mapping you are saying:

```
Id(x => x.Id, "InsuredId");
```

Which is information: My entity/class `Insured` has

```
Id(            // an identificator, the key
x => x.Id      // represented by the property **Id** (here is the issue)
, "InsuredId") // its DB representation is the column "InsuredId"
```

Other words, the C# property

```
public virtual int InsuredId { get; set; }
```

is **not** mapped, with the above statement, so it cannot be used for querying

What we can do in the query, to make it working is

```
var query = Session.QueryOver<Entities.Insured>()
    //.Where(x => x.InsuredId == insuredId)
    .Where(x => x.Id == insuredId)
    ...
```

And the *could not resolve property: InsuredId* exception will disappear, because we are using the mapped property `Id`

Comment: Which leads to the question, can you have a calculated field using Fluent Nhibernate?

Comment: Not fully sure, what are you searching for, but could [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13966856/1679310) help? We do have `formula=""` attribute in NHibernate...

Comment: More like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386981/fluent-nhibernate-and-computed-properties